# filled form gets reset on focus on IE only

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, input, focus

I have a page from which I get a "user" parameter in Javascript, to fill a login field and focus on another password field on that same page.

On FireFox and Chrome it works: my login field contains "user", and focus is on password field.

On IE: my login field seems to be replaced when the focus arrives on password. So I have an empty login field, and the focus on password.

```
user = getURLParameter('user'); //get my user parameter
$("input.login").val(user); //fill my login field
$('input.password').focus(); //focus on my password field
```

my login form:

> `<input type="text" placeholder="Login" class="login" value="" name="login">`

my password form:

> `<input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="password" name="password">`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$("input.login").val(user);`  to `$("input.login").attr("value",user);`

In IE it seems to take the value attribute from the  tag after the script has loaded.

EDIT: by using .attr(), it will replace the `""` in `value=""` with whatever is stored in `user`.